# Javascript : function bind.click & for each checkbox

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I have some combo box, every combo box have value and group by class & ID

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" class="box-1" id="ID_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="B" class="box-1" id="ID_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="C" class="box-2" id="ID_2"> 
<input type="checkbox" value="D" class="box-2" id="ID_2">
```

If user click button, then check each box, if this checked, store value & ID to variable.

EDIT :

JS :

```
$('#button').bind('click', function() {

var box = '';
var p =0;
var count = document.getElementById("count").value; // for count total class checkbox 

for(d=1; d <= count; d++){

    p = 0;
    $('.box-' + d).each(function(item){ // each box-1/2/3
        if(this.checked){
            if(p == 0)
            {
                var name = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
                box += '&' + ($(this).attr('id')) + '=' + '&' + encodeURIComponent(name).toLowerCase());
                p+=1;
                alert(box);
            }
            else
            {
                var href = ($(this).attr('id')) + '=';
                var name_2 = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
                box += href + '&' + encodeURIComponent(name_2).toLowerCase());
                p+=1;
            }       
        }
    });
}

alert(box);
//location = url;
});
```

example case :
the `checked` combo box is `A & D`
what i expect is `&ID_1=&AID_2=&D` ( this is different ID), if same ID = `&ID_1=&A&D`

when i try alert it's display nothing(''), but when i try alert(box) inside if( p== 0) it's have result `1&ID_1=A` and `0&ID_2=&D`.

Try check this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Blackarch/c8ue0d3d/5/)

Comment: You are using `box` as a variable in two places: as a string variable, and also as the input for your `each` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 change your code into like this

    $('#button').bind('click', function() {

    var boxval="";
    //&ID_1=&AID_2=&D
    $("input[class^='box-']").each(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {

    boxval += $(this).attr('id') +'=&' + $(this).attr('value');
    }
    });

    if(boxval !='')
    alert(boxval)
    else
    alert("nothing will selected");

    });




 below is the working fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/17hxsa9r/

Comment: @Newbi;  one suggestion . Please use unique ids only. don't use duplicate ids in a page. its create serious problems some time.

Comment: yes its posible. its push like a[0]="TEXTID_1" , a[1]="TEXTID_1" ,a[2]="TEXTID_2",a[3]="TEXTID_3" ........

Comment: var data = 'text'+$(this).attr("data-id");
a.push(data);  why you are adding this "text". if you adding this thing remaining functionality got effected.   both data-id and id are same for this thing . so dont add any extra text for data-id attribute.

Comment: ? like i ask before it's possible add 'TEXT'+$(this).attr("data-id"); and you say yes it's possible??

Comment: hmm.  In general its possible to push the value using that syntax, but in my fiddle remaining code is not satisfy  if u change the code. do you really check my code????

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `box` twice in your code

```
var box = '';
```

and

```
$('.box-' + d).each(function(box){ // each box-1/2/3
```

The `box` declared inside `each()` hides the outer `box`, therefore its value is not changed.

You need to name one of them differently.

Comment: change `$('.box-' + d).each(function(box){` to `$('.box-' + d).each(function(item){ ` and it should be good

Comment: I try follow your instruction but it's alert like this (coz i write alert twice + for) undefined&ID_1=&A , undefined&ID_2=&D, (nothing).